# Why my relation didn't work in my object with sale_order object

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I used odoo 10, my relation with my new object to sale.order didn't work, I used @api.onchange('product_id') only to check how my relation work...
 here's my 'paket.perjalanan' object design

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class Paket(models.Model):
    _name = 'paket.perjalanan'

    name = fields.Char(string='Reference', readonly=True)
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Sale', domain=[('type','=','service')], required=True)
    .......
    travel_line = fields.One2many('sale.order', 'travel_id', string='Paket Perjalanan')


    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def testing(self):
        print self.travel_line
```

here's my 'sale.order' inherit object

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class SaleOrderCustom(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    invoice_address = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Invoice Address', required=True)
    delivery_address = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Delivery Address', required=True)
    travel_id = fields.Many2one('paket.perjalanan', string='Travel Package', domain=[('state', '=', 'confirmed')])
    document_line = fields.One2many('sale.document.line', 'document_id', string='Dokumen Line', required=True)
    passport_line = fields.One2many('sale.passport.line', 'passport_id', string='Passport Line')
```

When I run @api.onchange('product_id') it only shows `sale.order()` it should shows like this `sale.order('some_id')` can anyone give me advice ?

Comment: Did you save the `sale order`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `@api.depends`

```py
@api.onchange('product_id')
@api.depends('travel_line')
def testing(self):
    print self.travel_line
```

Hope it will help you.